# Symfony2 fails silently after 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener'

Tags: symfony, development-environment

My Symfony2 project is failing silently. No fatal errors output in PHP, nothing in the PHP error log.

The last line of the dev.log is always:

```
[2012-12-27 01:14:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener 
 "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
```

Any ideas on why it is dying?

**Update**

Also worth noting this is on my prod server only. Local is fine.

Comment: Wouldn't that show an error? This is only taking around 10 seconds. Not the 30 second limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Managed to get an infinite loop in there using `forward()`.

It must have just crashed.